# Make a unique row that have the default value

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have table  `pricings` and each row of this table has column `price`, I want to :

1. Make a unique row that does have the standard value of `price`.
2. When I create new row, it will inherit automatically from the unique
   row that I have already mentioned when there is no value to put instead.
3. User will have the ability to change this standard value.

So what is the right way to do that ?

Comment: This question is rather vague. There's enough there to understand what you want to do, but not enough context to give a good answer. I would not store the unique changeable standard value in the same place as the normal prices and make it special by calling it "unique".

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following.

basically the price is a variable, $price = someDefaultValue

and then do the following.

```html
<input type="number" value="{{ ($row->price === null)? $price:$row->price }}" name="price" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could set the default value on the column (via migration for example: `$table->unsignedFloat('price')->default(100);`), but i don't think it makes sense to have a default price